# CSS Drop Down Menus not Disappearing

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, responsive

I'm working on an old website that the previous programmer actually died on whilst working on it (no I don't think it's cursed, but it is a bit of a maze of code that could feasably give someone a heart attack ;)

Anyway, I've been hacking and slashing my way through it and resolved many problems, including much of the responsive code that wasn't working correctly.

But I've been left with two problems that currently have me stumped.

Number one is that the drop down menus don't disappear (on mobile screen) when another drop down menu is clicked on. This creates a confusing layered effect.

The second problem is that the drop down option "Vacation rentals" brings up a search box, this is partially displaying off the side of the screen, and the internal date picker is also not displaying well. Any ideas?

Any ideas will be much appreciated! 
Thanks!

http://spldev.sanpancholife.com/

Comment: not visible dropdown here.

Comment: Just updated site as drop down was not previously displaying. It is now displaying but with the errors stated above. Any help would be much appreciated :)